# Getting displayed month as an integer from fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, jquery-ui

I wanted to fetch the current displayed month from fullcalendar with the following code:

```
function GetCurrentViewedMonth() {
    var date = $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
    var month_integer = date.getMonth();
    return month_integer;    
}
```

I have googled a lot and I got almost the same code. But it is not working for me (got error message: Property or method getMonth is not supported by the object).

Does the problem related with fullcalendar version? I have **2.3.1** version in my project. 
Is there an alternative way to fetch the displayed month correctly ?

Comment: What is the value in date variable? Can you console.log that?

Comment: Try var date = new Date(); before populating it.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf , the value of the date variable is the following: Tue May 19 2015 19:42:50 GMT+0200

Comment: @Ransher, I tried but it is not working.

Comment: I tried a quick JSFiddle and this works  var date = new Date('Tue May 19 2015 19:42:50 GMT+0200');
var month_integer = date.getMonth();
alert(month_integer); so please check your script again

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Ransher. Now it works by using your tip:

```
function GetCurrentDisplayedMonth() { 
var date = new Date($('#myCalendar').fullCalendar('getDate'));
var month_int = date.getMonth();
return month_int; 
}
```

--Added code block